# How to randomly pick more than one different array elements in C?

Tags: c, arrays, random

first of all I am new to programming and I'm trying to solve this problem. After dynamically creating an array of N integers (N is inserted by the user and the elements are random numbers), I am trying to randomly pick half of the elements (N/2) and randomly modify them. My code for randomly picking and modifying is as follows (b is the array and it's earlier declared in my code):

```
for(int j=0; j<(N/2); j++){
    int l=rand() % (N + 1 - 0) + 0;
    b[l]= rand() % (100 + 1 - (-100)) + (-100);
}
```

The problem is that in this way, there is a possibility that the same element is chosen for modification. How can I avoid this? I tried the following code but didn't work out.

```
int n=-1;
for(int j=0; j<(N/2); j++){
    int l=rand() % (N + 1 - 0) + 0;
    b[l]= rand() % (100 + 1 - (-100)) + (-100);
    if(l == n){
        j--;
    }
    n=l;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider either shuffling the array, then use the first half the entries entries, or if I couldn't re-order the array, I'd shuffle an array of indices instead, and then use them to point to the other array.

This would need lots of extra storage, which might or might not be a serious issue.  Shuffling is easy to get wrong, but easy to research and easy to find existing algorithms which do work.

Comment: Very nice idea and is one of those that I came up with, but then I would have to re-order the array the way it was, in order for the value modification to be clearly printed. Thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

How about having an extra array to keep track of elements already chosen, and as long as the element that `rand()` returns is one that has already been modified, selecting another? Like so:

```
int *temp = (int *) calloc(N, sizeof(int)); // initialize elements with all zero values

for(int j=0; j<(N/2); j++){
    int done = 0;
    int l;
    while (!done) {
        l=rand() % (N + 1 - 0) + 0;
        if (temp[l] == 0) {
            temp[l] = 1;
            done = 1;
        }
    }
    b[l]= rand() % (100 + 1 - (-100)) + (-100);
}

free(temp);
```

Note that this method requires O(n) extra space, which hopefully shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Note that this method requires O(n) extra space, which hopefully shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't let me initialize the temp array which is variable-sized, so I tried by not initializing and just declaring it, but still the same. Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I forgot. I've modified the answer- use malloc to declare the array, and free to free that space later on.

Comment: `if (temp[l] == 0) {` is undefined behavior as `temp[i]` has not been initialized. "// initialize elements with all zero values" is not true.

Comment: @chux: Thank you. I meant `calloc`, but wrote `malloc` by mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: `calloc(sizeof(int)*N);` does not compile. Check with compiler.

Comment: Sorry again. Fixed now :(